# Subdivision Surface causes distortions when extruding oder joining verts

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, loop

I am fairly new to this and have a question as I always get distortions as soon as I try to extrude any verts of this cylindrical shaped part of the mesh or when I try to connect Verts of this part with other verts from parts of the rest of the model.

The Subdivision Surface Modifyer is causing the distortions. As soon as I switch it off, it's gone. I applied All, flipped the normals (and flipped them back afterwards as it had no effect), Merged by Distance, tried adding a crease around the edge loop, added additional edge loops etc.

Has anyone any idea what is causing these troubles?

[image]

---

I added all the faces around the Edge Loop at the back and the distortions on the outside of the cylinder are finally gone indeed, but there is a white ring clearly visible now inside the cylinder.

[image]
Is there any chance to get rid of this?
Not quite sure, what is causing this.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. However, you'd have to create a *face* (suface) to make the subdiv modifier work properly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the expected behaviour: by extruding that vertex you're creating a "non-manifold" geometry. Check this answer for understanding what is manifold and why you should avoid non-manifold geometry.

[What is non-manifold geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry)